# Trying to match string that contains only spaces with regex

Tags: regex, vba

I have a string that is converted into ascii code.

Exemple: `"    "` (Three spaces) -> "323232"

I want for the regex to match the string ENTIRELY only if it has just spaces. I've tried endlessly with no luck. if there is another char other than space the regex wouldn't match.

Exemple: "3264" that will not match because it contains an 64 (A) in it.

Comment: `323232` is a regex that matches 323232 :/ `(32)*` might be what you want.

Comment: Well the string may contain other letters. I want to match the entire string if has just spaces in it, otherwise, there will be no matches.

Comment: Then you don't need a regex. What language are you using?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Take the example of 643252. Using (32)*, it will match 32 and my desired output is no matches because there is something different than 32 in the string.

Comment: I'm using Visual basic for apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match something repeatedly with `*`, and you can apply that to a sequence of characters by enclosing them in parentheses. So, you want something like `(32)*`.

If you're using a "search" rather than a "match" (depends on your language, how you're using the regex, etc) then you probably need to anchor the regex to the start and end of your string. Something like: `^(32)*$`. (`^` usually means "start of string" and `$` usually means "end of string".)

Comment: Doesn't do work bro. I've edited the question. Hopes it is clean now.

Comment: Doesn't work bro. That matches spaces even if the string contains a different char (non space). I want to match the entire string when it just spaces.

Comment: @Amejel I assumed you were using a function that matches against the entire string, but if you're not, I added an additional suggestion.

Comment: Beautiful. The anchor thing works. Many thanks. Would you mind explaining to me what an anchor is in regex?

Comment: @Amejel I've tried to answer above; ^ means "start of string" and $ means "end of string". It's just a figure of speech to say this anchors (as in "attaches" or "locks") the match to those places.

Answer (score 0):

You can then do something like this. The below is psedo-code

```
if(str.replace(/32/g,"") == ""){
   // match
}
```

What it does, is basically remove all 32's and check if the resultant string is an empty one, which suggests it was full of spaces in ascii code.